# drawing cards in the deck

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose 3 cards are drawn from a shuffled 52 card deck. The face cards are the Jacks, Queens, and Kings. Let A = {all diamonds} and B = {All face cards} Are the events A and B independent?

Independence formula is P(AB) = P(A)*P(B)

Comment: At $469$ reputation, I think you are aware that we ask for your thoughts and work in progress. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: What is the formula to check for statistical independence ?

Answer (score 3):

$P(A) = \dfrac{\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}},\quad P(B) = \dfrac{\binom{12}{3}}{\binom{52}{3}},\quad P(AB) = \dfrac{\binom{3}3}{\binom{52}3}$

Using your formula, you should be able to come to a conclusion !

Answer (score -1):

Yes!! They are independent. Prove it just from any of the definitions of independence. I will take one here.
 If two events are independent, $P(B|A)=P(B)$. Here $P(B|A)= $$3\over 13$*$11\over51$ + $10\over 13$*$12\over 51$ $=$$3\over 13$ = $P(B)$
$P(B|A) \implies$ Probability that face is picked second after a diamond on the first turn =
*(Probability that face diamond is picked)(Probability that face in picked next) + (Probability that non-face diamond is picked)(Probability that face is picked next)*

Comment: Can you add some justification as to how you computed P(B|A)?? And explain more of your thought process and enumeration?

Comment: @mary I tried with an edit. I can't explain better.

Comment: OK, however I think the answer you have is wrong. Could you type another approach at this problem?

Comment: @Mary $\mathsf P(B\mid A)$ is the probability of picking all three diamond face cards out of all the diamond cards (when it is *given* that all cards picked were diamonds).$$\mathsf P(B\mid A) = \frac{3!~10!}{13!}$$

Comment: @mary, if you ask for another approach, do you care to explain _why_ you think he is wrong?